Test Class for the Apex Class? In above I am calculating time spent by record in each stage? I tried writing test class but unable do test coverage?
In the below, I am calculating time spent by the record in each stage. I tried writing test classes but was unable to do test coverage.
trigger Approval_Agreement on Approval_Agreement__c (before insert,before update) {
    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        Approval_Agrrement_Handler.setStageChange(Trigger.New);
    }
    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
        Approval_Agrrement_Handler.updateTimeSpent(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldmap);
    }
}

Apex class >>>
public class Approval_Agrrement_Handler {
    public static void setStageChange(List<Approval_Agreement__c> newList){
        for (Approval_Agreement__c AA : newList ) {
            DateTime now = DateTime.now();  

            // Set the initial Stage_Last_Changed__c field to the current time for new records
            AA.Stage_Last_Changed__c = now;
        } 
    }
    
    public static void updateTimeSpent(List<Approval_Agreement__c> newList, Map<Id, Approval_Agreement__c> oldMap) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();   

        for (Approval_Agreement__c NewAA : newList) {
            Approval_Agreement__c oldRecord = oldMap.get(NewAA.Id);

            if (NewAA.Stage__c != oldRecord.Stage__c) {
                // Check if Stage_Last_Changed__c is null in the old record
                if (oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c != null) {
                    Long secondsSpent = (now.getTime() - oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c.getTime()) / 1000;
                    Long daysSpent = secondsSpent / 86400;
                    System.debug('Get the time spent: ' + daysSpent);

                    // Update the appropriate time tracking field based on the previous stage
                    switch on oldRecord.Stage__c {
                        when 'Initial Stage' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Slow Progress' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Active Ongoing Dialogue' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Verbally Agreed' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Legally Approved' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'PAM Checklist' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c = (NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'OPS Approval' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c = (NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Closed Won' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Closed Lost' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    // If Stage_Last_Changed__c is null in the old record, initialize it to the created date
                    //oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c = oldRecord.CreatedDate;
                    System.debug('First Update the StageLastDate: ' +  oldRecord.CreatedDate);

                    Long secondsSpent = (now.getTime() - oldRecord.CreatedDate.getTime()) / 1000;
                    Long daysSpent = secondsSpent / 86400;
                    System.debug('Get the time spent: ' + daysSpent);

                    // Update the appropriate time tracking field based on the previous stage
                    switch on oldRecord.Stage__c {
                        when 'Initial Stage' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Slow Progress' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Active Ongoing Dialogue' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Verbally Agreed' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Legally Approved' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'PAM Checklist' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c = (NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'OPS Approval' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c = (NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Closed Won' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                        when 'Closed Lost' {
                            NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c : 0) + daysSpent;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Update the Stage_Last_Changed__c field to the current time
                NewAA.Stage_Last_Changed__c = now;
            }
        }
    }
}

Test Class>>>
@isTest
public class Aprroval_Agrrement_HandlerTest {
    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
        // Create test data
        List<Approval_Agreement__c> agreements = new List<Approval_Agreement__c>();

        Approval_Agreement__c agreement = new Approval_Agreement__c(
            Name = 'Test Agreement ',
            Stage__c = 'Initial Stage',
            Fund_Company__c = a.Id,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.now().addDays(-2),  
            Stage_Last_Changed__c = DateTime.now().addDays(-2), 
            BatchUpdate__c = false
        );
        agreements.add(agreement);
        
        insert agreements;
        System.debug('Get the Inserted A&A Record Details'+agreements);
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testUpdateTimeSpent() {
        // Fetch the sample records
        List<Approval_Agreement__c> agreements = [SELECT Id, Stage__c, Stage_Last_Changed__c, CreatedDate,Time_In_Initial_Stage__c FROM Approval_Agreement__c];
        System.debug('Get the OLD A&A Record Details'+agreements);   
        
        // Update stages for some agreements
        for (Approval_Agreement__c agreement : agreements) {
            agreement.Stage__c = 'Slow Progress'; // Change the stage
        }
        System.debug('Get the NEW A&A Record Details'+agreements);
           
        // Map the old records for comparison
        Map<Id, Approval_Agreement__c> oldMap = new Map<Id, Approval_Agreement__c>([SELECT Id, Stage__c, Stage_Last_Changed__c, CreatedDate,Time_In_Initial_Stage__c FROM Approval_Agreement__c]);
        
        // Call the updateTimeSpent method
        Test.startTest();
        Approval_Agrrement_Handler.updateTimeSpent(agreements, oldMap);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify the time spent fields are updated correctly
        for (Approval_Agreement__c agreement : agreements) {
            Approval_Agreement__c oldAgreement = oldMap.get(agreement.Id);
            Long daysSpent = (DateTime.now().getTime() - oldAgreement.CreatedDate.getTime()) / 86400000;
            
            System.assertEquals(daysSpent, agreement.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c, 'Time_In_Initial_Stage__c should be updated correctly');
            System.assertNotEquals(null, agreement.Stage_Last_Changed__c, 'Stage_Last_Changed__c should be set to current time');
        }
    }
}


What have you tried so far? What are you struggling with? This website is for questions and answers, not for asking people to do your homework.

I added my test class for the above class. Please some can help me where I am doing mistake.

This question is similar to: How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The golden rule of unit testing is: you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of running the test method(s)
Since you currently only have a single test method, and are only working with a single test record, you're only going to get coverage for a very limited portion of your code.
Specifically, since the test record you're creating in your setup method goes through your trigger, you'll get into your if (oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c != null) { block which means you do not get into the else block. Since the old record stage is "Initial Stage", you'll only execute the first when in your switch statement.
So the one when block in the switch inside the if is the only code that gets executed. That's why that's the only code you will see be covered.
There are two main ways for you to improve coverage here

Make more test records and more test methods so you ensure that you get into both the if and else parts of if (oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c != null), and vary the value of Stage__c between them so you cover all of the when parts of your switch
Adjust your code to remove duplication and have fewer branches/make it easier to test

Specifically for #2, your big switch statements do basically the same thing in every branch. Once you select the field to work with, you're just adding days to it. If you were to, for example, use a map to store which field you're working on instead, you'd be able to use Sobject's .put() to handle every single when case but with a single line.
Instead of this
switch on oldRecord.Stage__c {
    when 'Initial Stage' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Slow Progress' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Active Ongoing Dialogue' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Verbally Agreed' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Legally Approved' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'PAM Checklist' {
        NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c = (NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'OPS Approval' {
        NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c = (NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Closed Won' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Won__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
    when 'Closed Lost' {
        NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c = (NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c != null ? NewAA.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c : 0) + daysSpent;
    }
}

Consider using a map to store field tokens based on the stage string
// You could make the map value a string instead of a field token, but field
//   tokens get you some compile-time checks to make sure you didn't misspell something
//
// Also, you would want to declare/initialize this map outside of your loop
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> timeFieldsByStage = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> {
    'Initial Stage' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Initial_Stage__c,
    'Slow Progress' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Slow_Progress__c,
    'Active Ongoing Dialogue' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Active_Ongoing_Dialogue__c,
    'Verbally Agreed' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Verbally_Agreed__c,
    'Legally Approved' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Legally_Approved__c,
    'PAM Checklist' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_PAM_Checklist__c,
    'OPS Approval' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_OPS_Approval__c,
    'Closed Won' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Closed_Won__c,
    'Closed Lost' => Approval_Agreement__c.Time_In_Closed_Lost__c
};

Schema.SObjectField targetFieldToken = timeFieldsByStage.get(oldRecord.Stage__c);
if(targetFieldToken == null) { 
    // no field for us to update, continue on to the next iteration to avoid an error
    continue;
}

// ?? is the null-coalescing operator, introduced in API v60.0
// Just a more compact way to do things. Same effect as your ternary.
Long existingTimeValue = NewAA.get(targetFieldToken) ?? 0;

NewAA.put(targetFieldToken, existingTimeValue + days);

You could take that a step further and also get rid of the if (oldRecord.Stage_Last_Changed__c != null) (and the corresponding else block). In that case, you're only choosing between whether you use Stage_Last_Changed__c or CreatedDate when you calculate days.
Those two things combined will make your code shorter (literally both fewer lines and fewer characters typed) and remove all of the extra branches that you were failing to cover before.
Do not take that as a license to slack off though.
You should still be creating additional test records and writing multiple tests (with assertions, assertions are the most important part of unit tests).
